# How return a response headers at my component with angular4

Tags: angular, function, service, return

Hi guys I've a problem with Angular4. 
I need to return a response header to my component but it doesn't works yet.
example of my component code:

```
this.filmService.create(this.film).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    //this.addFilmIntoDubberSelected();
    this.alertMessage = {
      "text": "Film has been created successfully!",
      "class": "success",
      "display": true
    }
  },
  err => {
    this.alertMessage = {
      "text": "Error occured!",
      "class": "danger",
      "display": true
    }
  }
);
```

this example of my service:

```
create(film: Film) {
return this.http.post(this.urlRoot, film, {headers: this.headers})
```

}
this return "null" always!!!

---

Sorry guys, I am trying to rewrite my question clearer
I need to access the response headers because I have to be able to read response.headers['location']. 
This is my code:

**In the user component I have a function which call my service**

```
create(){
  this.service.create(this.user).subscribe(
    data => {
     console.log(data);
    },
    err => {
     console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

**My service is this:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// Models
import { User } from '../_models/index';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private url = "http://localhost:3000/users";

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  create(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, user);
  }

}
```

What Do I have to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get the connection between the first and the second bit of code. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I updated my answer after your question edit. Hope I did understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me work like this:

```
 public create(newFilm: Film): Observable<boolean> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let body = newFilm.generateUrlencodedParameters(this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
        return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.createHomeboxP), body, {
          headers: headers
        })
          .map((response: Response) => {
            let res = response.json();

            if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
              return true;
          });
      }
```

Class.ts

```
 export class Film{
        id: string[];
        public generateUrlencodedParameters(token: string, id?: number): string {

            let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            urlSearchParams.append('id', this.id.toString());

            return urlSearchParams.toString();
        }
    }
```

component.ts

```
  public films: Film[] = [];

  this.cs.create().subscribe(
      films=> {
        this.films= films }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `HttpClient` will consider the return of a call as JSON and will parse it automatically. You can observe the full HTTP `Response` object with this code :

```
this.http.get('…', { observe: 'response' });
```

Working the same for POST. You'll get an object from which you can extract the headers.

Alternately, you can configure an HTTP interceptor.

Have a look at this [short and precise article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361) for more information.